# Any way to create a new worksheet using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Using Python `xlwings`, how can I create a new worksheet?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://docs.xlwings.org/quickstart.html#interact-with-excel-from-python

Comment: @ρss thanks. The document only gives how to get an existing worksheet rather than create a new one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
wb.sheets.add()
```

See also the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?#xlwings.main.Sheets.add).

Comment: I am trying to create a new sheet and I get: `TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` after I have given it a name between quotations.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following helper function to add a sheet if it is not yet existing or get/activate it, in case it is already present:

```
def addActivate(wb, sheetName, template=None):
    try:
        sht = wb.sheets(sheetName).activate()
    except com_error:
        if template:
            template.sheets["Template"].api.Copy(wb.sheets.active.api)
            sht = wb.sheets["Template"].api.Name = sheetName
        else:
            sht = wb.sheets.add(sheetName)
    return sht
```

It also allows to define the name of a sheet name to be used as template for the new sheet.